# Tubular neighborhood of compact set

Tags: algebraic-topology, reference-request, differential-topology

Let $X \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be a compact, connected non-empty subset. Does there exist an analogue to a tubular neighborhood for $X$, i.e. something like a smooth manifold with boundary that retracts to $X$? One can assume that $X$ has the homotopy type of a finite CW-complex.

I thought about using regular neighborhoods (which one could apply after maybe simplicially approximating $X$), but I think this delivers only a $PL$-manifold (and I am not sure if it really fits the desired properties). I also thought about considering the closure of an $\varepsilon$-neighborhood of $X$, but I do not know how I can guarantee that this is really a smooth manifold with boundary. Any help or reference for this topic is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Yes, if you assume that $X$ itself is locally contractible. Otherwise, no.

Comment: This question has to be about the topology of $X$, so only making assumptions on its homotopy type is definitely insufficient. For example, the Griffiths cone embeds as a closed subset in $\mathbb{R}^3$ and is contractible, hence has the homotopy of a CW-complex, but it cannot be the retract of any ANR (e.g. a manifold) for that would imply the earring space is an ANR.

Comment: @MoisheKohan do you have a reference for this result?

Comment: @Thorgott if we assume that $X$ really is an embedded CW-complex in euclidean space, does that solve the problem?

Comment: Any book which discusses ANRs, say Borsuk "Theory of retracts."  Start by reading about ANRs here: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Retraction_(topology)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In such general setup the answer is "no", because every retraction is a quotient map, and a quotient map preserves local connectedness. In particular [the comb space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comb_space) is not a retract of **any** manifold it is embeded in, because it is not locally connected. And it is contractible, and thus of finite CW homotopy type.

The property you are talking about seems to be the same as being absolute neighborhood retract (ANR). It is well known that every locally finite CW complex is an ANR. And so in the case $X\subseteq \Bbb{R}^n$ it is enough to assume that it is just CW.